# C++ Sub sequence Exercise

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I was assigned a "project" where I should create a C++ program to find the largest possible sum of two sub sequences. The user inputs N (array length), K (length of each sub sequence) and N numbers representing the array. The two sub sequences can touch but can't override each other e.g. 1 5 20 20 20 15 10 1 1 1 should output 90 ((5+20+20)+(20+15_10)) and not 115 ((20+20+20)+(20+20+15)).

My code until now is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int N, K, MaxN;
   cin >> N;
   cin >> K;
   int Pi[N];
   MaxN = N - K + 1;
   int Word[MaxN];
   int MaxSum;

   for(int nn=0; nn<N; nn++) {
      cin >> Pi[nn];
   }

   for(int y=0;y<MaxN;y++) {
      Word[y] = 0;
   }

   for(int j=0; j<MaxN; j++) {
      for(int l=0; l<K; l++) {
         Word[j] = Word[j] + Pi[j+l];  
      }
   }

   sort(Word, Word + MaxN);
   MaxSum = Word[MaxN-2] + Word[MaxN-1];
   cout << MaxSum;

   return 0;
}
```

Which is correct only in the case where the 2 sub sequences don't interfere with each other e.g. in an array such as 2 4 15 12 10 1 1 20 4 10 which outputs 71.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. Could you explain in more detail the cases in which your current code does and does not work?

Comment: Sure in the case of N=10  K=3
Array=2 4 15 12 10 1 1 20 4 10 my code works and efficiently outputs 71 (15+12+10)+(20+4+10). However, in the case of

N=10 K= 3
Array=1 5 20 20 20 15 10 1 1 1 my array doesn't work as it uses the same number in two different sub sequences and outputs 115 instead of 90.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is solution:

1. precalculate prefixes and suffixes
2. iterate *end* of the first subarray

   iterate *begin* of the second subarray, but start from the end of first sub. ar. + 1

   we have `sum of numbers on interval from 0 to *end* = prefix[end]`, but we are interested only in interval `[end - k, k],` so simply subtract `prefix[end] - prefix[end - k - 1]`

> [0 .. end-k-1, end-k .. end]

The same approach for the second subarray: `sum2 = suffix[begin] - suffix[begin + i + 1]`

then compare with the previous answer

So we just brute-force all possible sub-arrays which not intersect and find the max their sum

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N,K,MaxN;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> K;
    int Pi[N];
    MaxN=N-K+1;
    int Word[MaxN];
    int MaxSum;

    for(int nn=0;nn<N;nn++){
        cin >> Pi[nn];
    }

    int prefix[N];
    int sufix[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        prefix[i] = sufix[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            prefix[i] = Pi[i];
        else
            prefix[i] = Pi[i] + prefix[i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i == N - 1)
            sufix[i] = Pi[i];
        else
            sufix[i] = Pi[i] + sufix[i + 1];
    }

    int ans = 0;

    for (int i = K - 1; i < MaxN; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < MaxN; j++) {
            int x = prefix[i] - (i - K >= 0 ? prefix[i - K] : 0);
            int y = sufix[j] - (j + K < N ? sufix[j + K] : 0);
            ans = max(ans, x + y);

        }
    }

    cout << ans;




    return 0;
}
```